# Scenarios that can be implemented by WCF only but not with Web API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I've read a couple of articles recently suggesting that Web API can replace WCF; however on the other side some people still defending WCF by saying that it still has its usages.

My question is what are the scenarios where WCF is a must and you have no way of implementing them using Web API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically whenever you need a transport layer other than http webapi cannot be used. For example communication via Message Queues, Inter Process Communication (NamedPipe), direct TCP Socket connections.

WebAPI does not have Peer2Peer Communication, Bi-Directional communication, Reliable Messaging, Transaction Flows, Message Level Security, …

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this. For example I can have Peer2Peer with Web API if I add web sockets to the mix so is that not a replacement to WCF Peer2Peer communication?

Comment: With SignalR you can do Bi-Di, no real P2P. And SignalR is a completely separate technology. I mean, sure if you take 5 – 7 separate Frameworks (System.Messaging, .NET remoting, WebAPI, SignalR,…) you can replace WCF, but the whole point of WCF was to unify all these little Frameworks. Currently it looks like we are trying to split them up again. Nevertheless WebAPI and SignalR are great technologies properly used. But if I need a communication between a desktop application and a windows service I would rather use WCF than Self-hosting a WebAPI in my Windows Service to do IPC over HTTP.

Comment: What if you have given a scenario where business to business communication is needed. You are using .NET environement and you don't care what the other business is using. Typically your communication medium will be via http. Will you use WCF of Web API for such scenario and why?

Comment: @SulAga This, like every second answer to software development questions start with, well, it depends on. In this case it depends on how your API is specified. Is it a public api with a wide range of clients, highly scalable with less complex data structures like for example the facebook API. Go for REST and WebAPI. Do you have highly complex data structures and mainly .NET Clients I would use WCF with a netTcpBinding or wsHttpBinding and webHttpBinding Endpoint. So you can serve both, legacy and .Net clients with the same service.

Comment: @SulAga If you build an API for a SaaS based CRM system for web and mobile usage. - WebAPI Rest Service. If you build an OnPremise ERP system API – WCF because most of your corporate customers will use .NET to access your Service. With WCF you can out of the box provide them a .NET client component. Fast access (netTcpBinding), secure access (wsHttpBinding) and flexibility (webHttpBinding).